# Before I go implement this, would it work? Using Shared Pref as a backup to Parse-Server

Tags: android, android-intent, sharedpreferences, parse-server

I am trying to make this application load faster as well as when I pass data from one activity to another, I'm pretty sure it would disappear after awhile if the user clicks on the home button.

For example, I am changing the title of the new activity based off information from the previous activity. Does getStringExtra ever timeout?

I was also thinking about passing things into shared pref.
For example, once I click on an item in my list view, I am passing about 10 different strings into the next activity. If I put everything into a shared pref before I go into the activity, and then once I am in the activity call the shared pref information instead of the intent extra.

If the user goes back, I can either dump the shared pref, or just over right it if the user clicks on a different object in the list view.

Before I code it, would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably don't want to use shared prefs for storing large amounts of data, although it would probably work in some cases.

Look at parse local data storage. You can "pin" data that you fetch from the server locally, and then retrieve it wherever you want.

So for instance, when you fetch your list data, you can pin the list locally. When you click a list item, you can just pass the id of that object to the detail screen (in the bundle args), and then query by id in order to display it.

Here's an example from the docs:

```
// Pin ParseQuery results
List<ParseObject> objects = query.find(); // Online ParseQuery results
ParseObject.pinAllInBackground(objects);

// Query the Local Datastore
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.get("Feed")
    .fromLocalDatastore()
    .whereEquals("starred", true)
    .findInBackground(new FindCallback() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            // Update UI
        }
    });

ParseObject feed = ParseQuery.get(objectId); // Online ParseQuery result
feed.fetch();
feed.put("starred", true);

// No network connectivity
feed.saveEventually();

ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.get("Feed")
  .fromLocalDatastore()
  .whereEquals("starred", true)
  .findInBackground(new FindCallback() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
      // "feed" ParseObject will be returned in the list of results
    }
  });
```

Comment: Using this same concept. Can I (during the loading splash screen) query my data and just pin everything? Then just use the pinned data and go from there? I started to work with PIN. For example, when I created an object, I saved it, as well as pinned it. I found when I go back to my app the next day, the pined items didn't load when I tried to query from the local store

Comment: Yes you can fetch remotely and pin during the splash screen, or wherever it makes the most sense. What did you mean by "saved it as well as pinned it"? Did you mean also saved to shared prefs? And not sure why pinned data would not be available the next day without seeing your code. Did you accidentally overwrite it at some point, or are you clearing the local data store somewhere?

Comment: no. So when I created an object. I do something like parseObject.saveInBackground(new Save){if (e== null) {I PINN THIS OBJECT TO BACKGROUND}

Comment: I think I under what to do. during my splash, I can query my tables. when the tables successfully query, I pin the parse objects. Then inside of my app, I query from the local store.

Comment: such a easy concept and my brain was fried. thanks for the pointers

Answer (score 1):

Extras in the `Intent` do not "time out". Android keeps this data persistently in the framework. Even if your app is killed while in the background, when the user returns to the app, Android will recreate the `Activity` with the original `Intent` including "extras".

Comment: thank you... this is good to know. the extras kinda act as a shared pref.

Comment: Well, not really, but between 2 activities, yes.